# "No source available for.." using Nsight Eclipse Edition RC1 on OSX 10.8.1

Tags: eclipse, cuda, osx-mountain-lion, nvcc, nsight

I'm trying to use CUDA 5 RC1 on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.1. When debugging from Nsight Eclipse Edition I get the error:

> No source available for main()

I've verified that nvcc is set to use -g and -G to emit device and host debug symbols and that -O0 is set to disable optimizations.

Any ideas what the issue is or some other diagnostics I can carry out?

Comment: Did you build from within the Nsight or outside of it? I have not seen anything like this on 10.8.0, I will update my laptop to 10.8.1 and double-check.

Comment: I built from inside Nsight. I should add that I had the same issue on 10.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, for me at least, turned out to be that the architecture needed to be set to x64.

To do this, `right click` on your `project` and hit `Properties`.

Then go to `Build` --> `Settings` --> `Tool Settings`.

Under `NVCC Compiler` --> `Code Generation`, set `Architecture` to `x64`.

Under `NVCC Linker` --> `Miscellaneous` set `Architecture` to `x64`.

Finally, clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: Thank you. I will confirm the problem and will try to fix it for the final Nsight 5.0 build.

Comment: I have the same problem on my ubuntu 64 bits, but there is no Tool Settings under Settings